# knockout js drop down store list display on checkout page magento 2

Tags: magento2

app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/CustomConfigProvider.php  (data provider)

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;

class CustomConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
{

    public function getConfig()
    {        
        $storepick_config = array();    
        $storepick_config[] = ['value' => 1, 'label' => 'label1'];
        $storepick_config[] = ['value' => 2, 'label' => 'label2'];
        $storepick_config[] = ['value' => 3, 'label' => 'label3'];
        $storepick_config[] = ['value' => 4, 'label' => 'label4'];


        $config = [
            'storepick_config' => $storepick_config,
            'storepick_config_encode' => json_encode($storepick_config),
        ];
        return $config;
    }


}
?>
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/shipping/storepickup.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function ($, ko, Component, quote) {
    'use strict';   

    console.log(window.checkoutConfig.storepick_config);
    console.log(window.checkoutConfig.storepick_config_encode);

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Vendor_Module/checkout/shipping/storepickup',
            storepickConfig: window.checkoutConfig.storepick_config,
            storepick_config_encode:window.checkoutConfig.storepick_config_encode,

        },      

    });
});
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/shipping/storepickup.html

```
<select data-bind="options:storepickConfig"></select>
```

now i want require drop down in checkout page but drop down not display proper way

i want to display store list in drop down 
Please help if any one know

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `di.xml` file.

`/vendor/vendorName/module-myModule/etc/frontend/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="my_custom_config_provider" xsi:type="object">Vendor\ModuleName\Model\MyCustomConfigProvider</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

After this, clear all caches and check.